# Can't subtract months

Tags: pandas, datetime, subtraction, strftime

I am trying to subtract consecutive pairs of values in a pandas column list.
The values in the lists are strftime format.
it looks like this: `1  100005439431    [2021-04, 2021-11, 2022-04, 2022-10]`
I can't find a method on how to convert these strftime values into values that could be used in calculation.

I have tried so far to convert these columns into datetime values like this:
`df['date_obj'] = df['date_str'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x.strip('[]'), '%Y-%m'))` 
But all i get are errors like

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'strip'`
or
`TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable` 
Or something similar

Comment: The error means that you aren't dealing with a pandas DataFrame, like you think, but instead a Numpy Array. Check your types.

Comment: print(type(selection["year_month"])) it is <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: What is selection? You haven't posted a reproducible code sample with any variable called selection

Comment: Your `date_str` column has a numpy array and this parentheses `[]` is a notation for the array. So, you don't strip this characters. 
Try `df. date_str.transform(lambda x: [pd.to_datetime(item) for item in x])`